# Alternative to SharePoint Survey

Tags: wss-3.0, survey-list

We are designing a WSS 3.0 system.

One of the requirements is a questionaire. We had though of using the sharepoint survey, but this has some limitations:

- Displaying data from other systems
- Showing more than one question at a time on one page

Is there an alternative to surveys, for example connecting views together using a workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at using Data View Web Parts or InfoPath Forms (if IP is available to you).  If it is a public facing WSS3.0 site, then Data View Web Parts (or custom ASP pages) may be your best alternative.